# Android Firestore rules custom auth

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

We are using in out app Google sign in but also have function to "skip authentication"

For authenticated user we have the following rule

```
function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth != null;
    }
```

For "skip authentication" we are not using anonymous Firebase login, using kind of local caching mechanism.

The question is the a way to add rule for "skipped users" with some hardcored obfuscated token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to send extra information along with a query in order to authorize the query using security rules.  This is not secure, as anyone would be able to bypass the rules simply by knowing the "password" in this case.  All identity-based authorization must go through a Firebase Authentication user account - there are currently no alternatives.